# Convertir un número de octal a decimal usando un bloque For

Tags: vb.net, bucle-for

Tengo este código en un botón que pretende convertir un número de octal a decimal con dos bloques `For` pero sin importar el número que le ingrese da 0 y no se como corregirlo
¿Qué es lo que puedo estar haciendo mal?

```
Sub Button1Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim digito As Integer
    Dim decNum, octNum, remNum, j, i As Single
    
    digito = 0
    decNum = 0
    remNum = 0
    
    i = 0
    j = 0
    
    octNum = CLng(TextBox1.Text)
    
    For i = CInt(octNum) To i = i / 10 Step 1
       For j = 0 To octNum = Math.Pow(8,j) Step 1
         digito = CInt(i mod 10)
         decNum = CInt(decNum + digito * Math.Pow(8,j))
       Next
    Next
    TextBox2.Text = CStr(decNum)    
End Sub
```

Comment: Tienes que usar dos for obligado?

Comment: Bueno, si es uno mejor

Comment: Si que se usan dos bucles, pero no anidados... Uno coge digito a dígito el octal para convertir-lo a binario y despues en el de binario a decimal se hace también cogiendo dígito a dígito sumando o no en cada dígito binario...

Answer (score 1):

Al leer tu código me da la sensación de que te estás iniciando en la programación. Sea ese o no el caso, considero buena idea explicarte brevemente el funcionamiento de los ciclos.

Los ciclos `For, While, Do While` tienen un funcionamiento similar. Sencillamente se encargan de repetir las instrucciones en su interior.

Como habrás podido notar, dentro de un ciclo se puede ubicar otro y otro, y... en definitiva, todos los que necesites. Estos ciclos son dependientes, en concreto el interior del exterior. Veamos un ejemplo:

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 0

For contador1 As Integer = 1 To 5 Step 1
  For contador2 As Integer = 1 To 5 Step 1
    i += 1
  Next contador1
Next contador2 

Console.WriteLine(i)
```

Si ejecutas el ejemplo podrás notar que obtendrás 25. Resultado de que el programa está entrando 5 veces en el ciclo del `contador2`. En Visual Basic debes tener en cuenta que cuando usas `For` anidados, para que el compilador pueda diferenciar cuando es el final de cuál ciclo, debes indicar la variable que usaste en la inicialización del `For`.

Te dejo un gif de la página [Codebuns](https://codebuns.com/csharp-basics/for-loop/) sobre ciclos `For` anidados. Sé que es de C# pero el funcionamiento es bastante cercano al de Visual Basic. También te aconsejo depurar el programa con puntos de interrupción para ver lo que sucede en su interior y comprender mejor su funcionamiento.

[image: Ejemplo de https://codebuns.com/csharp-basics/for-loop/ sobre ciclos For anidados]

Volviendo a tu código, puedes simplificarlo, removiendo un ciclo, algunas variables e incluso no es necesario que las haya de tipo `Single` ya que no te interesan los decimales de los números.

El código sería algo así:

```
Dim i, digito As Integer
Dim decNum, octNum As Integer

octNum = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
decNum = 0
digito = 0
i = 0

While octNum > 0
    
    digito = octNum mod 10
    
    ' No es una verificación necesaria, pero con ella puedes saber si el número
    ' está mal escrito, dado que en octal solo se pueden usar dígitos del 0 al 7
    If digito > 7 Then
        Console.WriteLine("No es octal")
        Exit While
    End If
    
    decNum += CInt(digito * Math.Pow(8,i))
    ' Math.Floor es necesario ya que por defecto esta operación devuelve un número
    ' con decimales, el cual es redondeado y causa resultados inconsistentes
    octNum = CInt(Math.Floor(octNum / 10))
    
    i += 1
End While
```

Puedes ver que decidí reemplazar el `For` por un `While` ya que es más simple y adecuado para esta operación.

Comment: Yo lo quería hacer con For en vez de While

Comment: Decidí hacerlo así porque For no podía usar `octNum > 0` directamente. Lo importante es que hayas podido esclarecer dudas. Si insistes, una opción con For sería algo así:
`For i = 0 To 1000000` y en la siguiente línea deberías usar un If para chequear que octNum sea mayor a 0 y cortar el ciclo. `If octNum <= 0 Then`, otra línea `Exit For` y la última: `Exit For`

Comment: Si, me sirvió igual tu respuesta

Comment: Es implentado desde C#, pero es con un for muy rebuscado

Comment: https://www.discoduroderoer.es/convertir-de-octal-a-decimal-y-viceversa-en-c-sharp/ Acá el enlace

Comment: Su código funciona porque C# lo admite. Me gusta porque es un lenguaje flexible que digamos. Cómo puedes ver el usa un solo For. Lo que sucede es que en la sección de inicialización, inicializa 2 variables y en la sección de incremento o mejor dicho variación, da 3 instrucciones. Sumado a que en C# puedes darle cualquier condición al For. Solo basta con que le pases un booleano. Incluso puedes darte el lujo de dejar vacías las 3 secciones. En cambio, en Visual Basic el comportamiento del foro es fijo, tener un contador e incrementarlo o variarlo.

Comment: Lo que intento hacer es "clarificar" in poco la estructura del for e implementarlo en Vb.Net. Hace semanas que estoy con eso.

Comment: Cómo te digo, en VB el For viene de lujo cuando necesitas un contador que vaya aumentando o disminuyendo. Un ejemplo de equivalentes, en VB: `For contador As Integer = 0 To 10 Step 1`, en C#: `for(int contador = 0; contador <= 10; contador++)`. Puedes hacerte amigo de `While`, complicarte con `For` o aprender C# que además de ser más flexible y permisivo, sigue con soporte. También podrías darle una oportunidad a F# u otro lenguaje.

Comment: Es una lástima que no se pueda. Bueno, quedará con un While

Comment: Acá encontré algo https://www.matrixlab-examples.com/octal-to-decimal.html

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127189/discussion-between-mateo-and-alejandro-caro).

Answer (score 0):

Así se resuelve agregando-le 3 Funciones a ese Botón Que Ya Tienes Para Resolver el Posible Problema con los Octales...

Las constantes están de optimizador de código

```
Private Const StringCero As String = "0"
Private Const StringUno As String = "1"
Private Const StringDos As String = "2"
Private Const StringTres As String = "3"
Private Const StringCuatro As String = "4"
Private Const StringCinco As String = "5"
Private Const StringSeis As String = "6"
Private Const StringSiete As String = "7"
' Private Const StringOcho As String = "8"
Private Const Cero As Integer = 0
Private Const Uno As Integer = 1
Private Const Dos As Integer = 2

Public Function GetBinaryNumOctal(ByVal Num1 As String) As String
    ' Valores de 0 a 7
    Select Case Num1
        Case StringCero
            Return "000"
        Case StringUno
            Return "001"
        Case StringDos
            Return "010"
        Case StringTres
            Return "011"
        Case StringCuatro
            Return "100"
        Case StringCinco
            Return "101"
        Case StringSeis
            Return "110"
        Case StringSiete
            Return "111"
        Case Else
            Return "000"
    End Select
End Function


Public Function ConvertOctalToBinary(ByVal Num1 As Integer) As String
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim Man As Integer = Cero
    Dim Restante As String = CStr(Num1)
    Dim Resultado As String = vbNullString

    For Man = 1 To Len(Num1)
        Dim Numero As String = Right(Restante, Uno)
        Resultado = GetBinaryNumOctal(Numero) & Resultado
        Restante = Left(Num1, Len(Num1) - Man)
    Next

    Return Resultado

End Function

Public Function ConvertBinaryToString(ByVal Num1 As String) As Integer
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim CuentaDecimal As Integer = Uno
    Dim Man As Integer = Cero
    Dim Restante As String = Num1
    Dim Resultado As Integer = Cero

    For Man = Uno To Len(Num1)
        Dim Numero As String = Right(Restante, Uno)
        If CInt(Numero) = Uno Then
            Resultado = Resultado + CuentaDecimal
        'Else
        '   ' Suma 0
        End If
        CuentaDecimal = CuentaDecimal * Dos
        Restante = Left(Num1, Len(Num1) - Man)
    Next

    Return Resultado

End Function

Sub Button1Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   On Error Resume Next

   TextBox2.Text =  ConvertBinaryToString(ConvertOctalToBinary(CInt(TextBox1.Text)))
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Así se hacen dos bucles con funciones propias por separado, el que convierte de octal a binario, y el que convierte de binario a decimal y se les llama desde el botón...